# Como selecionar as ultimas linhas adicionadas em uma tabela mysql

Tags: sql, select

Tenho a seguinte tabela `sir_ter_conversa` que é um historico de conversas.

```
id|idterreno|idincorporadora|idusuario|msg|data
1 |    1    |      771      |   771   | a |2018-05-27 10:20:00
2 |    1    |      771      |   773   | b |2018-05-27 10:30:00
3 |    1    |      771      |   771   | c |2018-05-27 11:20:00
4 |    1    |      771      |   773   | d |2018-05-27 11:35:00
5 |    2    |      772      |   775   | e |2018-05-27 13:25:00
```

idterreno é o que agrupa as conversas, id incorporadora é o cliente, id usuario é quem escreveu a mensagem que pode ser o usuario ou o admin (id 773).

Eu preciso fazer uma consulta que traga as conversas agrupadas e quem fez a ultima interação, baseado no último id ou data. Nesse caso ele traria:

```
id|idterreno|idincorporadora|idusuario|msg|data
4 |    1    |      771      |   773   | d |2018-05-27 10:20:00
5 |    2    |      772      |   775   | e |2018-05-27 10:30:00
```

Tentei a opção abaixo, mas o problema é que ele não trouxe o último id que inseriu, trouxe o primeiro id.

```
SELECT idterreno, idusuario, max(data)
FROM sir_ter_conversa
GROUP BY idterreno
```

Nessa consulta ele traz idusuario 771 e não o 773:

```
idterreno|idusuario|max(data)
    1    |   771   |2018-05-27 10:20:00
    2    |   775   |2018-05-27 10:30:00
```

Comment: é coincidência ou quanto maior o `id` maior a `data` **SEMPRE**?

Comment: sim, o maior id sempre será a maior data

Comment: adiciona o `ORDER BY id desc` pra ver se resolve :P

Comment: o maior id sempre será a maior data, não maior de todas, será a maior dentro de cada "idterreno"

Comment: eu fiz isso, mas o problema é que ele traz idusuario da primeira linha adicionada, e não da ultima

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que essa consulta deva trazer o que você precisa:

```
SELECT C1.idterreno, C1.idusuario, C1.data
FROM sir_ter_conversa C1
WHERE C1.id = (SELECT max(C2.id) FROM sir_ter_conversa C2 where C2.idterreno = C1.idterreno)
GROUP BY C1.idterreno, C1.idusuario
```

Comment: funcionou perfeito, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que você tenha uma tabela como:

```
CREATE TABLE sir_ter_conversa
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    idterreno INTEGER,
    idincorporadora INTEGER,
    idusuario INTEGER,
    msg TEXT,
    data DATE
);
```

Contendo os dados:

```
INSERT INTO sir_ter_conversa ( id, idterreno, idincorporadora, idusuario, msg, data ) VALUES
( 1, 1, 771, 771,'a', '2018-05-27 10:20:00' ),
( 2, 1, 771, 773, 'b', '2018-05-27 10:30:00' ),
( 3, 1, 771, 771, 'c', '2018-05-27 11:20:00' ),
( 4, 1, 771, 773, 'd', '2018-05-27 11:35:00' ),
( 5, 2, 772, 775, 'e', '2018-05-27 13:25:00' );
```

Em `Postgres`, você pode usar uma combinação de `LIMIT` com o `ORDER BY DESC`, vejamos:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sir_ter_conversa
ORDER BY
  id DESC
LIMIT
   2;
```

Saída:

```
| id | idterreno | idincorporadora | idusuario | msg |       data |
|----|-----------|-----------------|-----------|-----|------------|
|  5 |         2 |             772 |       775 |   e | 2018-05-27 |
|  4 |         1 |             771 |       773 |   d | 2018-05-27 |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/95e4c/3

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar fazer dessa forma, acredito que vai te ajudar:

```
SELECT idterreno, idusuario, data
FROM sir_ter_conversa
GROUP BY idterreno ORDER BY data DESC;

mysql> SELECT id, idterreno, idusuario, data FROM teste GROUP BY idterreno ORDER BY data DESC;
+------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| id   | idterreno | idusuario | data                |
+------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
|    5 |         2 |       775 | 2018-05-24 14:39:00 |
|    1 |         1 |       771 | 2018-05-24 14:37:52 |
+------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
```